# How to marshal JSON with bigints?

Tags: json, go, type-conversion, biginteger

I have a `json` that contains a field with a `bigint`

`{"NETWORK_ID": 6000370005980500000071}`

The format I have before marshaling is `map[string]interface{}`

When I marshal it and print to console everything seems to be fine but this field actually creates problems due to its size in other mediums so I want to serialize it as a string.

`UseNumber()` seems to be for this purpose but it's only for decoding I think.

Is there any way that I can detect this kind of `bigint` number and make them serialize as strings?

Comment: I guess that tag won't work with `interface{}` in any case. Can you not use a defined struct? That gives you much more control. If you must use `interface{}`, you'll probably be limited to using a custom type with its own MarshalJSON implementation.

Comment: @Flimzy Unfortunately it's dynamic data where I stream from an SQL database and index to elasticsearch. I can try structs if I can define them on the fly but I don't think that's possible

Comment: Then a custom type is probably your only choice.

Comment: @Flimzy do you think you can provide me an example or some pointers to resources about customs types? I am bit new to Go and never used those before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to create a custom type that implements the [json.Marshaler](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) interface, and marshals to a string.  Example:

```
type MyBigInt big.Int

func (i MyBigInt) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    i2 := big.Int(i)
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf(`"%s"`, i2.String()), nil
}
```

This will always marshal your custom type as a quoted decimal number.