# How to marshal and unmarshal big.Int in JSON?

Tags: json, go, biginteger

The question [How to marshal JSON with bigints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48802728/how-to-marshal-json-with-bigints) is about marshaling `big.Int` values into strings in JSON. This question asks, how does one marshal *and unmarshal* `big.Int` values natively *as numbers* in JSON?

Passing around large values marshaled in this manner may be incompatible with other implementations of JSON, particularly JavaScript and [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/143), as [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-6) notes:

> Note that when such software is used, numbers that are integers and
> are in the range `[-(2**53)+1, (2**53)-1]` are interoperable in the
> sense that implementations will agree exactly on their numeric
> values.

Comment: @Flimzy The [JSON spec](https://www.json.org/) does not specify any maximum (or minimum) value for numbers. JavaScript may lose precision when handling integers larger than 2^54 due to treating all numbers as double precision floating point values but that is not true of all languages, and specifically isn't true of go. Indeed, using `int64` has the same implications vis-a-vis JavaScript compatibility but is still commonly used in go.

Comment: [RFC 7159](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-6) warns against using numbers outside the range [-(2^53)+1, (2^53)-1] in JSON, so what you are attempting is not generally considered portable, and should generally be avoided.

Comment: I added a note about the RFC to the question. I still think this is a valid use of JSON, which despite its first two letters is a general purpose serialization format. Using strings has its own problems, including both sides agreeing that they are numbers-as-strings and also JavaScript clients not coercing them to numbers.

Comment: I also added a link to relevant discussion on `jq`'s handling of large integers; passing one of these values through `jq` is not guaranteed to be a lossless transformation.

Answer (score 8):

Create a custom type `BigInt` which implements `json.Marshaler` and `json.Unmarshaler` like the following:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

type BigInt struct {
    big.Int
}

func (b BigInt) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(b.String()), nil
}

func (b *BigInt) UnmarshalJSON(p []byte) error {
    if string(p) == "null" {
        return nil
    }
    var z big.Int
    _, ok := z.SetString(string(p), 10)
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("not a valid big integer: %s", p)
    }
    b.Int = z
    return nil
}
```

Rationale:

- Implemented as a struct type embedding `big.Int` instead of as a subtype of `big.Int` so that the methods (Add, SetString, etc.) are kept
- MarshalJSON takes a value receiver so that marshaled values using `BigInt` don't have to use pointers
- UnmarshalJSON takes a pointer receiver because it modifies the receiver; however, types using BigInt still don't have to use pointers
- UnmarshalJSON works on a temporary value because the SetString method has undefined behavior on its receiver in the case of errors

As with `big.Int` the zero value is useful and is equal to the number 0.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! Note that this solution encodes/decodes from number types because the output isn't wrapped in quotes, so precision may be lost. Would recommend wrapping in quotes or wrapping json.(Un)Marshal with string values.

Comment: Yeah, this solution is only really suitable if you are both reading and writing the JSON with the same code. If you pass the JSON around and cross language or tool boundaries, you're bound to lose precision (e.g. `jq` turns all numbers into double precision floating point). I think strings are the better way to go in general.